# Inject @ViewScope cdi bean into JAX-RS resource

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jax-rs, cdi, omnifaces

I'm using MyFaces Apache 2.0.3 JSF, WAS 8.0.0.10

Currently I'm trying to inject an `@ViewScope` cdi bean, `@ViewScope` in **JSF 2.0** provided by **OmniFaces**'s library. But I get an error: 
`WebBeans context with scope type annotation @ViewScoped does not exist within current thread`.
When I try to inject an `@SessionScope` cdi bean, everything works fine.

Code of my **JAX-RS** resource:

```
@RequestScoped
@Path("/events")
public class CalendarResource implements Serializable {     
    @Inject
    private CalendarBean calendarBean;
    @Inject
    private PropertiesBean propertiesBean;

    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain; charset=utf-8")
    public Response getEvents(@QueryParam("calendarId") String calendarId,
                            @QueryParam("start") String start,
                            @QueryParam("end") String end,
                            @Context SecurityContext securityContext,
                            @Context HttpServletRequest req
                            ) {


        FullCalendar selectedCalendar = calendarBean.getFullCalendar();


        System.out.println(calendarId + " " + start + " " + end + " " + propertiesBean.getUser().getName());


        return null;

    }
```

Code of my **CDI** bean:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class CalendarBean implements Serializable {


    @EJB
    private CalendarEJB calendarEJB;

    @Inject
    private PropertiesBean propertiesBean;



    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        ...
    }

...
}
```

What am I doing wrong? As soon as I know, I can inject broader scope in a narrow scope. Thank you.

**UPDATE**: when I changed `@ViewScope` to `@SessionScoped`, everything began to work. May it be issue with **OmniFaces**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@ViewScoped` is tied to a JSF view, however durig a JAX-RS request, there's no means of a JSF view anywhere. There's no JSF view being restored during a JAX-RS request as the JAX-RS request is not initiated by submit of a JSF `<h:form>` which holds information about the JSF view state and would trigger the `FacesServlet` to restore the view.

`@SessionScoped` will indeed work if the JAX-RS request is fired in the same HTTP session as the JSF page. However I can understand that this scope is too broad. You might want to pass an additional request parameter identifying the current JSF view and get hold a mapping of it in the session scoped bean (which is basically how the JSF view scope works under the covers!).

`@ConversationScoped` should work if you pass along the `cid` parameter to the JAX-RS request.

This is not an OmniFaces problem. You'd face exactly the same problem with JSF 2.2 `@ViewScoped` due to the nature of it being tied to a JSF view.

Comment: Thank you BalusC, your help is invaluable.